# jQuery click() not working in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a plugin to process useful information for myself inside the Amazon seller central dashboard.

For some reason a `click()` call on a *Next page* link will not fire from inside the context script.

The code is running, but this does nothing:

```
var $next = $('a:contains(Next)');
$next.click();
```

but strangely this *works*:

```
var $next = $('a:contains(Next)');
window.location = $next.attr("href");
```

The example of the HTML of the link is:

```
<td align="right" valign="middle" width="60%" class="tiny">
    <nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/feedback-manager/view-all-feedback.html?ie=UTF8&amp;currentPage=2&amp;dateRange=&amp;descendingOrder=1&amp;pageSize=50&amp;sortType=Date">Next</a>
    </nobr>
</td>
```

Are there any restrictions on running click events inside Chrome extension? A button press on another page works just fine (although that one is structured differently - see below):

```
<a class="buttonImage" name="View all your feedback" href="https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/feedback-manager/view-all-feedback.html/ref=fb_fbmgr_vwallfb?ie=UTF8&amp;dateRange=&amp;descendingOrder=1&amp;sortType=Date">
    <span class="awesomeButton buttonLarge primaryLargeButton inner_button">
        <span class="button_label">View all your feedback</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM Elements [have a native `.click()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click). Therefore the following examples work:

`$('a')[0].click()` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/7kg335ew/)

`$('a').get(0).click()` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/33hybcaj/)

`document.querySelector('a').click()` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/q2ng8q3a/) - <sub>it's worth pointing out that jQuery **isn't** required</sub>

Relevant [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361).

---

Which leads me to assume that you can't programmatically change the URL when selecting a collection of elements (a jQuery object). I guess you need to select the individual DOM element. Therefore, the following *should* work:

```
var $next = $('a:contains(Next)');
$next[0].click();
```

Comment: This is a more useful answer for me. For completeness I would like to confirm that all browsers have a `click()` method on DOM elements though (although for my extension only Chrome matters of course).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I presume `$next[0].click()` worked? Here is relevant documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Comment: This works perfectly in a live situation. Many thanks for the references :) Very odd that it does not translate to a real click in jQuery.

Comment: But why does jquery click work in the console and not in the extension? (I've got the same problem)

Comment: @Daniel - Are you using the same code in your console and extension? Double check that the code is being called in your extension... you may have to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include the relevant code?

Comment: Same exact code. Console accepts `$(...).click()`. Extension only accepts `$(...)[0].click()`; --- That's quite curious, but I don't think it's worth asking a question for which I already have the solution.